# Yahoo messenger login

Tags: java, instant-messaging

Have you any sample code for login in Yahoo messenger through OpenYMSG using OpenYMSG jar which is on site

http://sourceforge.net/projects/openymsg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are test classes that show the correct implementation. LoginTest shows login examples.

Answer (score 0):

According to me all other project like OpenYmsg and jymsg are dead, or does not work fine. You  can use their library IM SDK yahoo. You can use this repository which works fine.
 https://github.com/aldrinm/messenger-sdk
For more description use this site
http://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/guide/